# Remove strange keybindings from YASnippet

Tags: key-bindings, yasnippet

I have YASnippet installed in emacs 24.5, which wasn't working and after a lot of different attempts at a fix, I now have the basics working, however - somewhere along the way - I have collected the following key bindings:

This isn't a question of altering the `TAB`behaviour (I've seen a lot of threads on that).

When I have yas-minor-mode enabled, I cannot type the letter 'c' at all.
Here is what is stored in my YASnippet minor mode keybindings:

```
Key bindings:
key             binding
---             -------

C-c         Prefix Command
TAB         yas-expand
c           Prefix Command     <---- *
<tab>       yas-expand

c -         Prefix Command     <---- *

C-c &       Prefix Command
C-c k       yas-expand

c - c       Prefix Command     <---- *

C-c & C-n   yas-new-snippet
C-c & C-s   yas-insert-snippet
C-c & C-v   yas-visit-snippet-file
```

Now I am no expert, but those I have marked look a little too funky.

**How can I remove them?**

I have tried recreating those bindings and setting them to `nil` - no joy.

If there is no fix, would deleting the package and reinstalling it solve the issue? I am not sure where those kaybindings are actually stored... ?

Comment: I like to use key bindings in my snippets, and yasnippet combs the snippet to see if there is a user-defined binding.  Perhaps one or more of your snippets have bindings inside them, so you could open them and have a peek for something like this:  `# binding: TAB r`  Perhaps you have one that begins with the letter `c`?  The most likely scenario, however, is that you are using someone else's configuration that you have copied where they thought the letter `c` should be a prefix key instead of being able to type the word *candy* like a normal person.

Comment: Yasnippet has a nifty help table that describes everything:  `M-x yas-describe-tables` -- you may wish to give that a try to see what shows up -- perhaps that will give you some more clues.

Comment: I think those key bindings are my mistake - I only installed from MELPA and tried adding a key binding myself - I must have evaluated an incorrect binding and deleted it... don't know how else they could be there as there is nothing shown in the `yas-describe-tables` - no key bindings or other clues I can find. All very empty.

Comment: I've posted a little guide to setting up yasnippet for buffer-local usage or using it on a per major-mode basis, instead of globally:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16742/how-to-install-setup-yasnippet-for-buffer-local-usage  You may wish to consider reducing your Emacs installation to the bare minimum -- 3 lines of code -- just to get yasnippet working properly, and then slowly add back your own user configuration until you find out where the problem is -- i.e., add back a little, test it, add back some more, test it, and keep going until you find the code that causes the problem.