# How to install/setup yasnippet for buffer-local usage?

Tags: yasnippet

The instructions for installing yasnippet globally are set forth in the Github `README.mdown` -- https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet -- and also in the comments at the top of `yasnippet.el` library.

I prefer not to to use yasnippet globally, and would rather enable it on a buffer-local basis or only for specific major modes.

How can I install/setup yasnippet for buffer-local usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest stable public release of Emacs.  In my case, I downloaded Emacs for OSX (version 24.5.1) from:  http://emacsformacosx.com/

Start Emacs.

```
M-x package-install RET yasnippet RET
```

Add the following lines to the `.emacs` file, save, restart Emacs:

```lisp
(package-initialize)
;; or, instead of using `package-initialize`, use the following:
;; (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-0.8.0/")

(require 'yasnippet)

;; This is the default location as of September 18, 2015.  Add more as needed.
(setq yas-snippet-dirs '("~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-0.8.0/snippets"))

(yas-reload-all)
```

In any buffer containing the following major-modes that are supported out-of-the-box, type `M-x yas-minor-mode RET`

```
c-mode
c++-mode
cc-mode
;; There are no sample snippets in the folder out-of-the-box
;; cperl-mode
csharp-mode
css-mode
emacs-lisp-mode
erlang-mode
f90-mode
html-mode
latex-mode
markdown-mode
nxml-mode
objc-mode
perl-mode
python-mode
rst-mode
ruby-mode
scala-mode
snippet-mode
sql-mode
text-mode
```

If so desired, verify that everything went well by typing:  `M-x yas-describe-tables RET`

To enable `yas-minor-mode` automatically for only certain major-modes, use hooks like the following example in the `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode)
```