# Whats the recommended way to install yasnippet for an emacs prelude user?

Tags: yasnippet, prelude

Is doing mkdir ~/.emacs.d/personal/snippets/

the correct way and putting snippets there?

I've been reading https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/issues/98

What I did:

```
;; personal.el
(prelude-require-packages '(                                                                                                                            
  yasnippet
))

;; yasnippet                                                                                                                                            
(add-to-list 'load-path
             "~/.emacs.d/personal/snippets")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
```

Added this snippet to the snippets folder:
    https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/blob/master/snippets/perl-mode/sub

Then restarted emacs

opened up up a ruby file ( emacs is an alias that does a -nw emacsclient)

```
emacs app/controllers/application_controller.rb
```

now on a new line I press sub and then tab, but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Here is a link to my previous write-up (from a few years ago) of how to install Yasnippet for buffer-local usage.  I have not tested it recently.  I do not use Prelude.  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16743/2287  One of the maintainers of Yasnippet is a regular here in this forum, so go ahead and wait for an official answer by someone who knows more than me ... :)

Comment: In the linked example of how to configure `yasnippet` (for buffer-local usage), the variable `yas-snippet-dirs` is customized to a precise location of snippets -- that folder contains subfolders with the major-mode names, and within those major-mode folders are the snippets for each major-mode.  In the edited example of the question above, the original poster has configured the `load-path` with the location for snippets.  Customizing the `load-path` is *not* the correct method for telling `yasnippet` where to find the snippets.